# ThreadStart doesn't accept a parameter

Tags: vb.net, networking, port

So guys i'm new at VB.NET and i wanted to create a simple program that pings and scans the open ports . But, pinging is ok but scanning ports isn't working it keep saying "ThreadStart is not accepting a parameter" and i dont know how to fix it .Anyways this the code of the port scan part:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = Start1.Value To End1.Value
        ' TT= temp threading
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        Dim TT As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ScanPort)
        TT.IsBackground = True
        TT.Start(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

?...so make it accept a parameter?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = start1.Value To end1.Value
        ' TT= temp threading
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        Dim TT As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ScanPort)
        TT.IsBackground = True
        TT.Start(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ScanPort(ByVal portToScan As Integer)
    Debug.Print("Scanning Port: " & portToScan)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

With **Option Strict On**, it'd look like this instead:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = CInt(start1.Value) To CInt(end1.Value)
        ' TT= temp threading
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        Dim TT As New System.Threading.Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf ScanPort))
        TT.IsBackground = True
        TT.Start(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ScanPort(ByVal portToScan As Object)
    Dim port As Integer = CType(portToScan, Integer)
    Debug.Print("Scanning Port: " & port)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```

Comment: Beware that this cannot compile when Option Strict On.

Comment: True...you'd change the parameter type to Object and **cast** it to the correct type within using another variable.